# Reassign javascript with let

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Are there any differences between the two ways described below? Which one should I use any why?

```
while (true) {
    let test = getValue();
    ....
}
```

And

```
let test;
while (true) {
    test = getValue();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`let` is **block-scoped** that means it will only exist within a `{...}` block.

You should use the first form if you do not plan on accessing the variable `test` outside of the `while` loop.

```
while (true) {
    let test = getValue();
    ....
}
```

You should use the second form if you need to access `test` from outside the `while` loop or to reuse it across iterations.

```
let test;
while (true) {
    test = getValue();
    ....
}
```

Please also note that it is better to use `const` if you are not planning on reassigning another value to `test`.

Comment: The `const test` is unset after each iteration so I can use const inside the loop?

Comment: yes a new `test` variable will be created during each iteration. You can use it inside the loop as long as you don't need to override it during each iteration.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you use *test* variable outside your while loop, go with the second:

```
let test;
while (true) {
    test = getValue();
    ....
}
if (test) { ... }   // <--- Use test outside the while loop
```

Otherwise, the first one is better

Comment: So there's no downsides in using let multiple times on the same variable?

Comment: No, there is no problem

Answer (score 3):

Yeah there is a difference in the first version you cannot access the variable test outside of the while loop. In the 2nd version you can access the test variable outside of the loop.

Comment: I'm only ever going to access it within the block. I'm just wondering if there's any downsides using the let multiple times on the same variable?

Comment: No there is no downside but if you only use the variable inside the block you should declare it inside the block. Because of readability reasons.

Comment: @unska `let` just determines the scope of the variable, and it's explicitly meant to be used in scopes smaller than a function, i.e. `while` blocks or `if` blocks. This is exactly how you're meant to use `let`.

Comment: @LucasRosenberger: There can be a performance impact, but of course it only matters if the loop is running a **lot** of times.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are differences:

- In the first example, you have a **separate** `test` variable for each loop iteration; in the second case, you have only one `test` variable shared by all loop iterations. This has important effects if you create any functions in the loop, and can have a performance aspect (though of course, like all performance aspects, it's only a problem when it's a problem).
- In the first example (each) `test` variable is only accessible within the loop; in the second, the one `test` variable is accessible outside the loop as well.

> Which one should I use any why?

The right one for the situation. If you need a separate `test` variable for each loop or just want it to be private to the loop, use the first; if not, use the second.

Comment: In the first approach, the variable `test` would be scheduled for garbage collection when the enclosing function returns (Don't consider a closure case). But what about the second approach? How many memory references would be created and erased? And would all the created references be scheduled for garbage collection after each iteration?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: As I said above, in the first case, there's a separate `test` variable for each loop iteration. It's available for GC when the loop iteration completes, provided nothing closes over it.

Answer (score 2):

In the first version, variable's scope is limited in while loop while in another one variable can be accessed outside while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are differences between both of them.

- If you declare the variable outside the loop, it can be **updated in the loop & then be accessible in other code outside the loop**.
- And if you declared it in a loop, it can **only be updated & accessible in that loop**.

Answer (score 0):

`let` has a **block-scope** - that means that the variable will only exist **within its surrounding pair of curly brackets**. So, in this situation when we try to print the value of `let` after the loop, it will return `undefined`.

```
while (true) {
    let test = getValue();
    console.log(test); // => some value...
    ....
}
console.log(test); // => undefined
```

In this situation, `test` is already defined before the while loop (curly brackets), so it will be preserved outside of the while loop:

```
let test;
while (true) {
    test = getValue();
    console.log(test); // => some value...
    ....
}
console.log(test); // => still some value...
```

Note that even if you use `let` inside the while loop as well as outside, it will treat it the same:

```
let test = 5;
while (true) {
    let test = 4;
    console.log(test); // => 4
    ....
}
console.log(test); // => 4, not 5
```

So don't go trying to define your own special block-scoped variable independent of the main one

I will not give a runnable code example otherwise you will end up in an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

let is block-scoped which means it will only exist within a {...} block.

so, if you want to access the let value outside of the loop, you have to use this,

```js
let data;

while (true) {
  data = getData()
}
```